# Azure CLI: get object id from user name or email address

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-xplat-cli

I'm trying to automate detection of current user's oid using Azure CLI in order to perform queries on my application data. If I use the command `account show`, I get this:

```
azure account show
info:    Executing command account show
data:    Name                        : Visual Studio Enterprise
data:    ID                          : 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012
data:    State                       : Enabled
data:    Tenant ID                   : abcdef12-abcd-1234-abcd-1234abcd1234
data:    Is Default                  : true
data:    Environment                 : AzureCloud
data:    Has Certificate             : No
data:    Has Access Token            : Yes
data:    User name                   : peter.parker@outlook.com
data:
info:    account show command OK
```

Look at `peter.parker@outlook.com`. Now if I use the command `ad user list`, I get this:

```
azure ad user list
info:    Executing command ad user list
\data:    Object Id:       9123abcd-ffee-dafa-d0fa-abacfede1234
data:    Principal Name:  peter_parker_outlook.com#EXT#@peter_parkeroutlook.onmicrosoft.com
data:    Display Name:    Peter Parker
data:    E-Mail:
data:
+
info:    ad user list command OK
```

The principal name is `peter_parker_outlook.com#EXT#@peter_parkeroutlook.onmicrosoft.com`. It doesn't match.

Any idea on how can I get the current user's object id?

Comment: You are using a live ID, and I can see that the principal name is following the naming policy of a principal name to a live id. Why do you say it doesn't match?

Answer (score 4):

There is a simpler way now then other answers to get this directly using Azure CLI with the "id" parameter.

```
MY_ID=$(az ad user show --id user@email.com | jq -r .id)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I get an users `objectId` by email address:

```
az ad user list --filter "mail eq 'first.last@acme.com'" --query "[].id" -o tsv
```

or in combination with the current Az CLI context - when signed in as user:

```
az ad user list --filter "mail eq '$(az account show --query user.name -o tsv)'" --query "[0].id" -o tsv
```

> azure-cli version used : 2.34.1

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current user's object id through powershell cmdlets.

```
$msolcred = Get-Credential
Connect-MsolService -Credential $msolcred
$user = Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName peter.parker@outlook.com
($user).ObjectId
```

Note that before running the above powershell, you need to first install the [Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant for IT Professionals RTW](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41950) from the Microsoft Download Center. Then install the [Azure Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell (64-bit version)](https://bposast.vo.msecnd.net/MSOPMW/Current/amd64/AdministrationConfig-zh-hans.msi), and click Run to run the installer package.

Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/b7727a57-b002-4d84-a20c-3192b1d6b1b4#BKMK_ManageUsers for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't. Microsoft Account authentication you are reffering to is the "consumer" one, and have nothing (at least, external) in connection with the Azure AD. For being able to do what you are trying to do, i think, you can try to join the machine into the domain or authenticate to the Azure using the AAD credentials, not the Microsoft Account. I strongly suspect there is no way to get the OID (if that even exists with the MS Account and externally available) of the user you are referring to in your question.

So, try to use for your situation only AAD users, not Microsoft Account.